# How do I capture a hyperlink that has a customized text present in a mail body

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

My outlook add-in is currently capturing the body content of an email using the below code

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
        "text",
        function (result) {
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                body = result.value;
                $('#item-Content').text(body);
            }
        }
    );
```

It is capturing hyperlinks that does not have a customized text. For example, it is capturing [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), but does not capture the same link with a customized text like "click me".

Comment: It looks like you're extracting text only. The actual links are stored in the `href` attribute on anchor (`<a>`) tags. So you'll need to extract HTML from the email instead of text.

Comment: Hey, if the “CoercionType” is text it just prints out the body as plain text. Could you try the same with “Html”?If the body has “www.bing.com”, the result would be,

{"value":"<div class="\&quot; …>www.bing.com</div>","status":"succeeded","asyncContext”:”…}

If the body a hyper link that points to “www.bing.com”, the result would be,

{"value":"<div class="\&quot…><a href="\&quot;http://www.bing.com\&quot;" title="\&quot;www.bing.com\&quot;" data-loopstyle="\&quot;linkonly\&quot;" id="\&quot;LPNoLPOWALinkPreview\&quot;">Click here</a></div>…>

You can extract the link from a href tag

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT could OP use the [DOMParser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to look for links with combining the DOM API?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes, we can use DOMParserAPI

Comment: `const content = '<p>Visit <a href="https://www.bing.com">Bing</a> website</p>';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(content, 'text/html');
const linkElements = doc.getElementsByTagName('a');
const links = Array.from(linkElements).map((linkElement) => linkElement.href);
console.log(links);`

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT  I need to send the mail body to another application as it is. Say, I extracted the mail body and parsed it to get the hyperlinks. Now how do I place these href in the mail body at the right places

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the HTML markup instead of plain text message body:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
        Office.CoercionType.Html,
        function (result) {
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                body = result.value;
                $('#item-Content').text(body);
            }
        }
    );
```

See [Office.CoercionType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.coerciontype?view=common-js-preview) enum for more information.

Comment: If `result.value` will be a string of HTML, consider using `$('#item-Content').html(body);` to append the HTML.

Comment: This returned the body content of the mail in html format. What I wanted was to just capture the links along with the other plain texts. I need to send the mail body to another application. Is there a way to extract only specific part of the body as html and rest as plain text?

Comment: Currently we do not have any API to extract specific body as plain and rest as HTML.

Comment: I need to display the link within the body exactly as it is customised but when clicked it needs to be redirected to the webpage. For example, "Hello there, the link is Visit Me" needs to be displayed as the same and the visit me as a link. I don't want the entire sentece to be extracted as a html. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

We have API to either get the whole body as text or whole body as HTML. Currently the feature, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.